# News table remove duplicate values based on one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

OK, so I have a table called NewsEvent with these columns:

- NewsID
- EventID
- UserID
- SameEvent

Now I'm only dealing with the first 3 columns right now, and basically what I want to do is get the number news that are connected to the same event, but the problem is that multiple users can link a certain news to an event, and I only need that news counted only once.

Say there's event with ID = 1, there's 5 News and 3 users have linked these 5 news with the event, using my query I would get a result of 15 news linked to the event.

Now the query in itself is correct, but how can I modify it to count news only once, and remove duplicate values when counting based on the News column so the result it returns is 5, not 15.

My query is as below:

```
Select count(NE.NewsID) as [Number of news linked to the event], NE.EventID as EventID
From NewsEvent NE
Group By NE.EventID  
Order By Count(NE.NewsID) Desc
```

I'm using SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want `count(distinct)`:

```
Select count(distinct NE.NewsID) as [Number of news linked to the event],
       NE.EventID as EventID
From NewsEvent NE
Group By NE.EventID  
Order By Count(NE.NewsID) Desc;
```

Comment: omg, I was putting the distinct before the bracket, and wondering why it wasn't working, not inside it, I can't believe I'm so stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Hi,
You can use the below query,

> With out duplicates (distinct values)

```
Select count(distinct NE.NewsID) as [Number of news linked to the event], NE.EventID as EventID
From NewsEvent NE
Group By NE.EventID  
Order By Count(NE.NewsID) Desc
```

> Only duplicates

```
Select count(NE.NewsID) as [Number of news linked to the event], NE.EventID as EventID
From NewsEvent NE
Group By NE.EventID  
Order By Count(NE.NewsID) Desc having count(NE.NewsID) > 1
```